# How to reduce time for a python program?

Tags: python

I have two files. File 1 has 6 million entries with 34 columns and size is 1.9GB, file 2 has 5 million with 16 columns and size is 950 MB. I have to compare a few columns line by line. I am using csv.DictReader to open and store the file. And I am using functions to check the values within a particular column. It is taking a huge amount of time. Is there any way to shorten the time? Like should I use a single for loop and if statements instead of multiple functions?

```
import csv

def tsv_to_dict(filename):
    with open(filename,'rb') as tsvfile:
        data = list(csv.DictReader(tsvfile, delimiter = '\t'))
    return data

original_file = tsv_to_dict('original.tsv')
processed_file = tsv_to_dict('processed.tsv')
```

The functions I am using is of the following types:

```
def validate_class_id():
    for entry in processed_file:
        for item in original_file:
            if item['section_ID'] == entry['sID']:
                if not item['class ID'] == entry['cID']:
                    print("Invalid class ID in processed file")

validate_class_id()
```

I have 5 such functions I am using.

Comment: Depending on your ram, you could either use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org) or [dask](https://dask.org). Check the respective documentation to get further information. We'd need more information/data to provide a solution with code.

Comment: This question is faar to broad. Please [edit] your question, show us your current code and try to specify which lines you'd like to improve. Feel free to mention `@xenteros` in comment when you improve this question so I can vote to reopen this question

Comment: Could you add some more information? Do the columns have the same name? What sort of comparison are you doing?

Comment: You probably should be using a database, not text files.

Comment: Disk access can take time. Where do these files reside ? in RAM, on SSD disk, on rotative disk ?

Comment: You may find [mcve] as a good guide to providing more details for your question.

Comment: I have added the details of the code I am using.

Comment: if you just need to compare line by line you can use `diff` cli tool.

Comment: 'tsv' file means that the data is structured so I will suggest loading it into a database and doing the comparison there

Answer (score 1):

You'd be much better using something like numpy.where() and pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = pd.read_csv('pathtofile1')
data2 = pd.read_csv('pathtofile2')

match = np.where(data1[section_ID].values == data2['sID'].values)
```

Match will now be a list of indexes where sID is the same.

np.where() is a vectorised operation. Vectorised operations are MUCH faster than looping - take a look at this link to help yourself learn: https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6

Comment: This one is working, but I am confused. I was using isin() and a lot of mistakes were happening, is this fullproof?